# Can you draw the children before the parent in WINAPI?

Tags: c, winapi

I have a parent window handle (`HWND`) and some child window handles (`HWND`), I add those to the parent.

The parent has a buffer (`HBITMAP`) which the children are supposed to draw on, their drawing procedure is inside of `WM_PAINT`. For the respective children they use that buffer for their drawing procedure. Then, the parent draws  that buffer onto the screen.

The problem now is that the `WM_PAINT` is first sent to the parent, then the parent draws the buffer, then the children draw onto the buffer; I want it the other way around.

Is there a way to do this, maybe with some special flags `WINAPI` has?

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish here? I'm not asking about the solution you have decided on using, just the overall effect you wish to get.

Comment: @IInspectable I want to make custom controls that draw onto the parent buffer. I am using this extra buffer to avoid any flickering.

Comment: The desktop compositor already buffers things for you. @gse The `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` window style conveniently prevents that.

Comment: The children draw on the same *custom* buffer. That buffer is drawn by the parent. But I want to fill the buffer before drawing the buffer.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to re-invent the `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` [extended window style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles).

Comment: @IInspectable Do you just know everything about `WINAPI` or do you just know for what terms to look for when searching on e.g. the microsoft docs (honest question)?

I am not sure if that is exactly what I need but it looks like it. Can this flag just be used with `CreateWindow` and is there things I should do in order to properly use this?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm..., according to WinAPI philosophia, a child window should neither know of its parent nor try to write anything outside its own area. You may have a good reason to require a global drawing at the same time, but then you cannot rely on the normal Window processing of WM_PAINT message, because what you are designing is not a custom control but a custom object able to cooperate with a container to help that container to draw itself.

IMHO the only reasonable way to achieve that is to have a custom handling of the WM_PAINT message in the container, that loops over the *cooperating objects* to have them to fill the buffer, and finally draws the buffer. And that should **not** happen during the processing of a WM_PAINT messages by the child objects.

It does require the container to be aware of its *children* but IMHO is still reasonably modular, and better fits in the Windows graphical system.

But beware, this is heresia, according to the Windows philosophia, so you should only go this way if no other path is possible.

Comment: Your approach *Custom handling of the WM_PAINT message [...] by looping over the cooperating objects* seems valid. Now I need to know how to loop over the children tho or save an array of drawing functions or something I reckon.